# nginx rewrite/location collision

Tags: nginx, webserver, url-rewriting

I have the following in nginx:

```
# backend
location /backend/ {
    deny all;
}

rewrite ^/aaaa/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.jpg$ /backend/u/$1/$2/$3.jpg last;
rewrite ^/bbbb/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.json$ /backend/u/$1/$2/report.json last;
```

but unfortunatelly I get 403 for the 2 rewrites.

Here is the question, how can I serve these files from /backend/* through the rewrites but block anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this patch:

```
location /backend/ {
-    deny all;
+    internal;
}
```